# jQuery statement based on browser type

Tags: jquery

I have the jQuery browser plugin and I'm trying to put together an if statement to add some classes based on the users browser type. I know there are easier ways to do this but I have to do it with jQuery. The statement below isn't working for me. I can get an alert to pop up but addClass isn't working.

```
var bro = $.browser;
if (bro.chrome) {
    $("#wrap").addClass("chrome");
}
```

Comment: [It looks like this test case works fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/FQfsC/)

Comment: I agree, it works fine. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EUbkK/)

Comment: Have you got that code in a document ready handler, or in a script block that appears after the `#wrap` element? If you just put it directly in the `<head>` the element won't have been parsed when the JS runs. (By the way, why do you care what the user's browser is?)

Comment: on my chrome on ubuntu I get safari

Comment: FYI, `$.support` is generally recommended much more than browser user agent detection.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for your comment, I moved the code to the end of the document and it now works. I just want to add a two classes for ie7 and ie8. Like I mentioned before, I know there are easier ways to do this but I have to use jQuery.

Comment: jQuery's browser detection has been deprecated in favor of feature detection. Do you have a *really good* reason to try to detect what browser is being used?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code to detect the browser in one of my js file.

> (function($) {
>       var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

$.browser = {
        version: (userAgent.match( /.+(?:rv|it|ra|ie)/: / ) || [0,'0'])[1],
        safari: /webkit/.test( userAgent ),
        opera: /opera/.test( userAgent ),
        msie: /msie/.test( userAgent ) && !/opera/.test( userAgent ),
        mozilla: /mozilla/.test( userAgent ) && !/(compatible|webkit)/.test( userAgent )
    };

```
})(jQuery);
```

and applied the the condition : if (jQuery.browser.msie) to check IE(here) where i needed to check the browser type .
Hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: And regarding the class is not added .I just checked your jsfiddle and found its working . just check out by adding the line           $('.chrome').remove();               and the div is removed .thanks.